# Available Youtube APIs for video streaming

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am looking for a solution to implement Youtube video streaming in my app, which is a part of a custom launcher. I need to implement certain features that follow the design of the rest of the bundled apps.

There are several options to perform this task but none fits my needs.

- Android Youtube Player API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

  - cons: requires Youtube app to be installed (not great but I can deal with that), does not allow any overlay view (I do need that - it allows a window actionbar overlay but it's not enough)
- Using a WebView and iframe API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

  - cons: handling playback through a javascript interface, reduced control, difficult management

So my question is: what are other options to implement a full screen youtube video playback, with overlay controls? Are there other APIs, than the two mentioned, that can handle this? Is there a way to get some raw stream?

Comment: You can look into using ExoPlayer to play Youtube videos. Just search online for examples. - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: Thanks but I think you've misunderstood. ExoPlayer is an alternative to the built-in MediaPlayer - once you have a data source, it allows you to handle playback. What I need is an API I can get this data from - if I had a stream or a file, then I would be able to handle it any way I want. The two APIs I mentioned are the only ones I know that give me any access to Youtube videos.

Comment: AFAIK, those two are the only option to play video streaming. As stated in the documentation - [Sample Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Overlay_ActionBar_Demo), Overlay ActionBar Demo shows how you can overlay an action bar on the player when it is in fullscreen mode. And Custom Player Controls displays several custom controls to demonstrate the use of YouTubePlayer programmatic controls. You might follow this sample to check code implementation regarding a full screen youtube video playback, with overlay controls. Hope this helps.